# Draw a directory tree

Tags: python, tree, file-system, formatting

My goal was to create a simple-to-use CLI program for drawing directory trees (what `tree` does on most platforms, basically). I'm submitting my 'backend' program for review because I think it makes more sense to review the actual algorithm, rather than reviewing an interface on top of it.

```
import os            
import re


def tree(path, indentation=4, ignore_hidden=True, regex=None):
    """Build a directory tree starting at `path`. See also
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Files11_directory_hierarchy.svg

    Arguments
    * path: A relative or absolute path to use as starting point
            for the tree. [type: str]

    * indentation: The amount of spaces to indent each level with.
                   Defaults to 4. [type: int]

    * ignore_hidden: Ignore hidden files (starting with a period).
                     Defaults to True. [type: boolean]

    * regex: If set, only matching files will be shown.
             Set to None to show all files. Defaults to None.
             [type: str / None]

    Returns
    * A directory tree [type: str]

    Example
    Assuming we're in the 'home' directory:

        >>> import tree
        >>> t = tree.tree(path="./")
        >>> t

        ./images
            foo.jpg
            bar.jpg
            ./images/personal
                spam.png
        ./documents
            eggs.docx

        >>> t = tree.tree(path="./", ignore_hidden=False)
        >>> t

        .hidden.txt
        ./images
            foo.jpg
            bar.jpg
            .hidden.jpg
            ./images/personal
                spam.png
        ./documents
            eggs.docx

        >>> t = tree.tree("./", 8, regex="(.*\.png)")
        >>> t

        ./images
                ./images/personal
                        spam.png
        ./documents
    """
    structure = "\n"
    tab = " "*indentation
    if regex is None:
        for root, directories, files in os.walk(path):
            try:
                depth = root.count(os.sep)
                offset = tab * depth
                structure += offset + root + "\n"
            except OSError:
                continue
            for f in files:
                if ignore_hidden and f.startswith("."):    
                    continue
                try:
                    depth = os.path.join(root, f).count(os.sep)
                    offset = tab * depth
                    structure += offset + f + "\n"
                except OSError:
                    continue
    else:
        restriction = re.compile(regex)
        for root, directories, files in os.walk(path):
            try:
                depth = root.count(os.sep)
                offset = tab * depth
                structure += offset + root + "\n"
            except OSError:
                continue
            for f in files:
                if ignore_hidden and f.startswith("."):    
                    continue
                if not re.match(restriction, f):
                    continue
                try:
                    depth = os.path.join(root, f).count(os.sep)
                    offset = tab * depth
                    structure += offset + f + "\n"
                except OSError:
                    continue
    structure = structure.split("\n")
    dedented = list(map(lambda e: e.replace(tab, "", 1), structure))[1:]
    return "\n".join(dedented)
```

I believe my code runs in \$O(n)\$ complexity and running it on my Android phone on `/` takes about 9 seconds:

```
time python -c "import tree; tree.tree('/')"

real    0m9.365s
user    0m7.390s
sys     0m1.630s
```

I'd appreciate any feedback regarding performance, usability, coding style, documentation, or anything else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to whether regex is None, you run code segment A or B. This feels like a copy-n-paste "bolt-on" to add the regex feature.

I suggest that you may be able to refactor A & B into a common piece of code that pays attention to `regex` and Does The Right Thing.

You didn't publish any automated unit tests that exercise this code. Putting together some unit tests would help you to refactor while verifying that functionality is unchanged.

You have some KPIs, and you mentioned 9s wall clock time, but did not mention how many directory entries were parsed in those 9 seconds. It would be interesting to know what sort of inputs this code expects, and where a profiler says the code spends most of its time.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I split the function into two blocks because I figured checking for an `re.match` in a `for`-loop's a real waste of time if no regex was passed in the first place. Can you recommend another way of approaching that?

Comment: Profile it first, then optimize for `regex is None` or whatever. I'd expect sys calls for os.walk() to dominate the usermode CPU time that checks a regex. Anyway, consider refactoring the common tree walking code into a generator function that repeatedly `yield`s file entries.

Comment: In `dedented` you strip TABs. If you're looking to save a few CPU cycles, perhaps you'd prefer not to insert TABs in the first place. Also, `replace()` is more aggressive than `re.compile(r'^ +')` or `lstrip()` -- for example a filename might be "READ[4 spaces]ME.txt".